# error installing audio_common

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-electric, ubuntu-oneiric, audio-common

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been following the instructions for downloading and installing audio_common.
I'm running electric on Ubuntu 11.10

I get this error:

```
$ rosdep install audio_common
Failed to find rosdep libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev for package audio_capture on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
```

I am unsure how to proceed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40485/error-installing-audio_common/) by [DocSmiley](https://answers.ros.org/users/2536/docsmiley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2012-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-sound-drivers
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DocSmiley](https://answers.ros.org/users/2536/docsmiley/) on 2012-08-03**:
That did it, thanks!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-03**:
If this answers your question, please click on the check mark circle (that helps others).